# Group by every 3 record

Tags: sql

How to achieve this(SQL)?

My Table

```
id    sub
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      1
6      2
7      2
8      2
```

The result should be like below

```
groupid   id   sub              groupid    id    sub
   0       1    1                   0       1    1
   0       2    1                   0       2    1
   0       3    1                   0       3    1
   1       4    1         or        1       6    2
   1       5    1                   1       7    2
   2       6    2                   1       8    2
   2       7    2
   2       8    2
```

My current query is

```
SELECT (id - 1) / 3 groupid, id, point FROM student
```

Comment: What RDBMS? Are `id` values guaranteed to be contiguous?

Comment: You've given two desired outputs?  Which do you actually require?

Comment: you're sure that the problem is well-defined?

Comment: well defined and understood problem is half solved :D

Comment: yes. id is guaranteed to be contiguous. I prefer the first result.

Comment: Any particular reason that group 1 should only have 2 members, and the others 3? (ie id 4 & 5 are special cases in both desired results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: The first `DENSE_RANK()` in my original answer could be eliminated to simply end up with;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUB ORDER BY ID) as rn, id, sub
FROM student)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sub,(rn-1)/3) as groupid, id, sub FROM cte;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6347/2).

-- original answer --

Assuming SQL server, you can use `DENSE_RANK()` to your advantage;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sub) AS rank,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUB ORDER BY ID) as rn,
       id, sub
FROM student)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sub,rank,(rn-1)/3) as groupid,
id,sub FROM cte;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6347/1).

Comment: I suspect one could eliminate the first `DENSE_RANK`, but sadly I can't reach SQLfiddle to try it right now. I'll get back on that later.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (id - 1) div 3 as groupid, id, point FROM student
```

Comment: @dijkstra : i guess you shuld write `SELECT (((id - 1) % 3) + 1) groupid, id, point FROM student`, but this method does not group, but repeat an increment every 3 rows